# How do I determine the area that is inside the circle r=3cos(θ) and outside the r=3sin(2θ) curve (For the first quadrant)

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have this graph here, but how do I find out the area that's inside the circle but outside the 3sin2θ rose shaped curve? I'm lost, please help me solve this

[image]

Comment: Have you thought to convert to cartesian coordinates and then integrate to find area under curves : HINT- Area between two curves one above the other (say $f(x)$ is upper curve and $g(x)$ the lower one), bounded by vertical lines (say $x=a$ and $y=b$) , is given by : $\int_a^b f(x) - g(x)\,dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of a region in polar coordinates defined by the equation $r=f(θ)$ with $\alpha\leq\theta\leq\beta$ is given by:$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \frac{1}{2}{r}^2 \; d\theta$$

The area of a region between two functions in polar coordinates is just the difference in area between the two functions in that region .  First, find $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which is where $r$ is equal in the two functions:
$$3\cos{\theta}=3\sin{2\theta} \implies \theta=\pm\frac{\pi}{6}$$
Note that you're looking for the area only in the first quadrant.  Try finishing the rest given what I have provided here.

Comment: So do i need to integrate (3costheta)^2 - (3sintheta)^2 with the upper limit being pi/6 and lower limit -pi/6? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You're missing the 1/2, and bounds should be 0 to pi/6 (its only the first quadrant as you specified in the description of the question)

Comment: Solved. Thanks. you're a legend